# How can I set default monospace font for \texttt{} in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I am able to set default text font using `\newfontfamily\mainfont{}`.

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\mainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
Foo
\texttt{Bar}
\end{document}
```

How can I similarly set the default monospace font that is used for text rendered with `\texttt{}`?

Comment: The main font is set with `\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}`, the monospaced font (for `\texttt`) with `\setmonofont{...<font name>...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the main part of `fontspec` documentation. At page 7, you find

[image]

So you should do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase
] % or whatever font you prefer

\begin{document}

Foo
\texttt{Bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]